# How to verify in CSS that text fields/other fields are disabled for editing in Selenium 2?

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The page is created by CSS using jquery and I am using selenium2 and junit for verification. It would be of great help if anyone can provide a way to identify that the fields are disabled and use an assert statement.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using Selenium 2 for your tests.

The `WebDriver` class provides a way to retrieve all `WebElements` on the page using the `findElement` and `findElements` methods. Both of these methods take selectors in the form of instances of the `By` class. So, in your case, you would have to use a selector that finds the input fields you are looking for, for instance with

```
WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.name("password"));
```

You can then use

```
if (element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled()) {
  //your code here
}
```

or

```
assert (element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled());
```

to verify that the field is both displayed and enabled.

Comment: isEnabled() check should be sufficient IMO